# Javascript checklist: Edit and Delete button

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, checklistbox

I need to make a Javascript To Do list (checklist), which I have already completed, but I cannot figure out how to make an edit and delete button also appear with each of the items the are entered. [Here is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6bBp.png)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ToDoList.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1> To Do List</h1>
  <div id = "listBox">
    <input type="text" id="inItemText"><button id = "btnAdd">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="tasks-parent">
    <h4>Tasks:</h4>
    <ul id = "todolist">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src ="ToDoList.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
#btnAdd {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #22B473;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}

.tasks-parent {
  border: 2px solid #777;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 17%;
}

html {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 400px;
}

li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
}

li span {
  padding-left: 17px;
}
```

```js
function updateItemStatus() {
  var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
  var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);
  if (this.checked) {
    itemText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  } else {
    itemText.style.textDecoration = "none";
  }
}

function addNewItem(list, itemText) {
  var date = new Date();
  var id = "" + date.getMinutes(); + date.getSeconds() +
    date.getMilliseconds() + "";

  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.id = "li_" + id;

  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.id = "cb_" + id;
  checkBox.onclick = updateItemStatus;

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.id = "item_" + id;
  span.innerText = itemText;
  listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
  listItem.appendChild(span);
  list.appendChild(listItem);
}

var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
inItemText.focus();

var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
  var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
  var itemText = inItemText.value;
  if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
    return false;
  }

  addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);
};

inItemText.onkeyup = function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    var itemText = inItemText.value;

    if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
      return false;
    }

    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);
    inItemText.focus();
    inItemText.select();
  }
};
```

Comment: I've just properly indented your code for you. Proper indentation is something you should make a habit of doing. It makes your code much more readable and easier to debug. Plus, people don't tend to answer questions with poor formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create additional two elements(one for edit and one for delete) and append them like you did with other elements:

```js
function updateItemStatus() {
  var cbId = this.id.replace("cb_", "");
  var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);

  if (this.checked) {
    itemText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  } else {
    itemText.style.textDecoration = "none";
  }

}


function addNewItem(list, itemText) {

  var date = new Date();
  var id = "" + date.getMinutes(); + date.getSeconds() +
    date.getMilliseconds() + "";

  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.id = "li_" + id;

  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  checkBox.id = "cb_" + id;
  checkBox.onclick = updateItemStatus;

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.id = "item_" + id;
  span.innerText = itemText;
  //create edit
  var edit = document.createElement("a");
  edit.href = "#";
  edit.innerText = "edit";
  //create delete
  var deleteBtn = document.createElement("a");
  deleteBtn.href = "#";
  deleteBtn.innerText = "delete";


  listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
  listItem.appendChild(span);
  //and append them in li
  listItem.appendChild(edit);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  list.appendChild(listItem);
}

var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
inItemText.focus();

var btnNew = document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
  var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");

  var itemText = inItemText.value;
  if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
    return false;
  }

  addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);
};

inItemText.onkeyup = function(event) {

  if (event.which == 13) {
    var itemText = inItemText.value;

    if (!itemText || itemText === "" || itemText === " ") {
      return false;
    }

    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);

    inItemText.focus();
    inItemText.select();
  }

};
```

```css
#btnAdd {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #22B473;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
}
.tasks-parent {
  border: 2px solid #777;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 35%;
}
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 400px;
}
li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
}
li span {
  padding-left: 17px;
}
li a {
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1> To Do List</h1>
<div id="listBox">
  <input type="text" id="inItemText">
  <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="tasks-parent">
  <h4>Tasks:</h4>
  <ul id="todolist">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much! I am having trouble writing the code to actually edit and remove them now

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the buttons inside your appended span.  Also need to change .innerText to .innerHTML

```
span.innerHTML = itemText + "<button>Edit</button><button>Delete</button>";
```

add classes to the inserted buttons to style